# How to do indexOf √ (sqrt character)

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

How would I check whether a string contains the √ symbol?

```
var string = '√ foobar'
if (string.indexOf("f") > -1) { alert(string); }
```

Searching for "f", this finds the "f" in "foobar" fine. For what it's worth, the √ character does show as âˆš in the alert though:
[image: foobar]

```
var string = '√ foobar'
if (string.indexOf("√") > -1) { alert(string); }
```

Searching for "√" doesn't do anything, no alert message.

Comment: Can you confirm that `string.charCodeAt(0)` returns 8730 (0x221A "SQUARE ROOT")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me

```js
var string = '√ foobar'
if (string.indexOf("√") > -1) {
  alert(string);
}
```

But maybe the javascript environment which you are in, doesn't recognize the symbol, so I suggest you to try with the Unicode of that symbol. `\u221A`

```js
var string = '√ foobar'
if (string.indexOf("\u221A") > -1) { alert(string); }
```

Comment: Using the unicode worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let example = '√ example';
console.log(example.includes('√'));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes